# KVM: Connecting an isolated virtual network to a DMZ virtual network

Tags: networking, kvm

My goal is to setup a virtual network in the following manner. I would like to have one network, 10.0.2.0/24, setup as with NAT networking, allowing hosts in it to talk to the Internet. I would like to setup another network, 10.0.1.0/24, which is isolated from the Internet. However, I'd like for it to be able to talk to a host in the DMZ, for example a CentOS package mirror or some other function.

I have my DMZ currently setup with a single CentOS server. I have no problem accessing the Internet from this machine. On the isolated network, I also have a CentOS server. It cannot see the Internet or the DMZ at this time.

Is there a way to configure KVM on the host to route traffic between the DMZ network and the isolated network? Also, for each virtual network, does it have a default gateway address by default?